# Matrix Multiplication using divide and conquer approach

Tags: c, recursion, matrix-multiplication, divide-and-conquer

I am a beginner in programming and just learned new concepts and started writing code for matrix multiplication but I got confused in pointers and others so I am uploading my code here in seek of guidelines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **matrixMultiply(int A[][8], int B[][8], int row);

int main() {
    int **A = allocate_matrix(A, 8, 8);
    int **B = allocate_matrix(B, 8, 8);

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            A[i][j] = i + j;
            A[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    int **C = allocate_matrix(C, 8, 8);
    C = matrixMultiply(A, B, 8);

    return 0;
}

int **matrixMultiply(int A[][8], int B[][8], int row) {
    int **C = allocate_matrix(C, row, row);
    if (row == 1) {
        C[1][1] = A[1][1] * B[1][1];
    } else {
        int a11[row/2][row/2], a12[row/2][row/2], a21[row/2][row/2], a22[row/2][row/2];
        int b11[row/2][row/2], b12[row/2][row/2], b21[row/2][row/2], b22[row/2][row/2];
        int **c11 = allocate_matrix(c11, row/2, row/2);
        int **c12 = allocate_matrix(c12, row/2, row/2);
        int **c21 = allocate_matrix(c21, row/2, row/2);
        int **c22 = allocate_matrix(c22, row/2, row/2);

        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < row/2; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < row/2; j++) {
                a11[i][j] = A[i][j];
                a12[i][j] = A[i][j + (row/2)];
                a21[i][j] = A[i + (row/2)][j];
                a22[i][j] = A[i + (row/2)][j + (row/2)];
                b11[i][j] = B[i][j];
                b12[i][j] = B[i][j + (row/2)];
                b21[i][j] = B[i + (row/2)][j];
                b22[i][j] = B[i + (row/2)][j + (row/2)];
                c11[i][j] = C[i][j];
                c12[i][j] = C[i][j + (row/2)];
                c21[i][j] = C[i + (row/2)][j];
                c22[i][j] = C[i + (row/2)][j + (row/2)];
            }
        }

        c11 = addmatrix(matrixMultiply(a11, b11, row/2),
                        matrixMultiply(a12, b21, row/2), c11, row/2);
        c12 = addmatrix(matrixMultiply(a11, b12, row/2),
                        matrixMultiply(a22, b22, row/2), c12, row/2);
        c21 = addmatrix(matrixMultiply(a21, b11, row/2),
                        matrixMultiply(a22, b21, row/2), c21, row/2);
        c22 = addmatrix(matrixMultiply(a21, b12, row/2),
                        matrixMultiply(a22, b22, row/2), c22, row/2);

        // missing code???
        return C;
    }
}

int **allocate_matrix(int **matrix, int row, int column) {
    matrix = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        matrix[row] = (int *)malloc(row * sizeof(int));
    }
    return matrix;
}

void deallocate_matrix(int **matrix, int row) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        free(matrix[row]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

int **addMatrix(int **a, int **b, int **c, int row) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: edit description and add the problem you are facing.

Comment: Change matrix[row] = (int *)malloc(row * sizeof(int)); this to matrix[row] = (int *)malloc(column * sizeof(int));
You did not face problems because both row and column is 8. If column is more than row, your code will have problems.

Comment: There are good reasons a pointer is not called "array" and vice-versa. `int **` is a "pointer to pointer", while `int (*)[]` is a "pointer to array" .

Comment: There is no point in passing the `matrix`-parameter to `allocate_matrix`.

Comment: @Sri.U: Do not cast `void *` in C!

Comment: @Olaf, thanks. that's right.

Comment: Why do you have two copies of the loop body in `main`?  Did you intend for one of them to initialize `B` instead of `A`?

Comment: yes @TomKarzes can anyone provide me better solution for this because i am getting so many errors and not able to resolve them

Comment: @RATHORE: I posted a corrected version, with a few extra gimmicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reformatted your code so I could analyze it.  Indent consistently with 4 spaces, insert spaces around binary operators, after `,` and `;` separators and between keywords and `(`, this improves readability a lot.

There seems to be missing code in the `matrixMultiply` function: you allocate the resulting matrix `C` but you use it as an input to initialize the intermediary matrices `c11`, `c21`, `c21` and `c22`, and never actually store anything into `C` except for the trivial 1x1 case.

The matrix multiplication code seems broken beyond this, the function takes 2 arguments of type `int A[][8], int B[][8]`, but you recursively call it with local arrays `a11` to `b22` defined as `int a11[row/2][row/2]`. These types are different, I do not know how the code even compiles.

In the matrix allocation code, you allocate rows with in incorrect size `row` instead of `column`.  You should use `calloc` for this so the matrix is initialized to `0`, plus you should not pass the initial argument at all:

```
int **allocate_matrix(int row, int column) {
    int **matrix = malloc(row * sizeof(*matrix));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        matrix[i] = calloc(column, sizeof(*matrix[row]));
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

There is also a mistake for the second submatrix multiplication, it should be

```
    c12 = addmatrix(matrixMultiply(a11, b12, row/2),
                    matrixMultiply(a12, b22, row/2), c12, row/2);
```

Furthermore, you never free the temporary matrices used for intermediary results.  Unlike java, C does not have a garbage collector, you are responsible for releasing blocks of memory when you no longer need them, before they become inaccessible.

Here is a corrected version, with extra functions to print the matrix data and verify the matrix multiplication correctness.  I added timings: the recursive method is **much** slower than the direct method, mostly because of all the extra allocation/deallocation for the intermediary results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int **matrix_allocate(int row, int column) {
    int **matrix = malloc(row * sizeof(*matrix));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        matrix[i] = calloc(column, sizeof(*matrix[i]));
    }
    return matrix;
}

void matrix_free(int **matrix, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

void matrix_print(const char *str, int **a, int row) {
    int min, max, w = 0, n1, n2, nw;
    min = max = a[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            if (min > a[i][j])
                min = a[i][j];
            if (max < a[i][j])
                max = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    n1 = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", min);
    n2 = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", max);
    nw = n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            w = printf("%s = ", str);
        else
            printf("%*s", w, "");

        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            printf(" %*d", nw, a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

int **matrix_add(int **a, int **b, int row, int deallocate) {
    int **c = matrix_allocate(row, row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    if (deallocate & 1) matrix_free(a, row);
    if (deallocate & 2) matrix_free(b, row);

    return c;
}

int **matrix_multiply(int **A, int **B, int row, int deallocate) {
    int **C = matrix_allocate(row, row);
    if (row == 1) {
        C[0][0] = A[0][0] * B[0][0];
    } else {
        int row2 = row / 2;
        int **a11 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);
        int **a12 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);
        int **a21 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);
        int **a22 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);
        int **b11 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);
        int **b12 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);
        int **b21 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);
        int **b22 = matrix_allocate(row2, row2);

        for (int i = 0; i < row2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row2; j++) {
                a11[i][j] = A[i][j];
                a12[i][j] = A[i][j + row2];
                a21[i][j] = A[i + row2][j];
                a22[i][j] = A[i + row2][j + row2];
                b11[i][j] = B[i][j];
                b12[i][j] = B[i][j + row2];
                b21[i][j] = B[i + row2][j];
                b22[i][j] = B[i + row2][j + row2];
            }
        }

        int **c11 = matrix_add(matrix_multiply(a11, b11, row2, 0),
                               matrix_multiply(a12, b21, row2, 0), row2, 1+2);
        int **c12 = matrix_add(matrix_multiply(a11, b12, row2, 1),
                               matrix_multiply(a12, b22, row2, 1), row2, 1+2);
        int **c21 = matrix_add(matrix_multiply(a21, b11, row2, 2),
                               matrix_multiply(a22, b21, row2, 2), row2, 1+2);
        int **c22 = matrix_add(matrix_multiply(a21, b12, row2, 1+2),
                               matrix_multiply(a22, b22, row2, 1+2), row2, 1+2);

        for (int i = 0; i < row2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row2; j++) {
                C[i][j] = c11[i][j];
                C[i][j + row2] = c12[i][j];
                C[i + row2][j] = c21[i][j];
                C[i + row2][j + row2] = c22[i][j];
            }
        }
        matrix_free(c11, row2);
        matrix_free(c12, row2);
        matrix_free(c21, row2);
        matrix_free(c22, row2);
    }
    if (deallocate & 1) matrix_free(A, row);
    if (deallocate & 2) matrix_free(B, row);

    return C;
}

int **matrix_multiply_direct(int **A, int **B, int row, int deallocate) {
    int **C = matrix_allocate(row, row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            int x = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < row; k++) {
                x += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
            C[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
    if (deallocate & 1) matrix_free(A, row);
    if (deallocate & 2) matrix_free(B, row);

    return C;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = argc < 2 ? 8 : atoi(argv[1]);
    int **A = matrix_allocate(n, n);
    int **B = matrix_allocate(n, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            A[i][j] = i + j;
            B[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    matrix_print("A", A, n);
    matrix_print("B", B, n);

    if ((n & (n - 1)) == 0) {
        /* recursive method can be applied only to powers of 2 */
        clock_t ticks = -clock();
        int **C = matrix_multiply(A, B, n, 0);
        ticks += clock();
        matrix_print("C = A * B", C, n);
        printf("%d ticks\n", ticks);
        matrix_free(C, n);
    }

    clock_t ticks = -clock();
    int **D = matrix_multiply_direct(A, B, n, 1+2);
    ticks += clock();

    matrix_print("D = A * B", D, n);
    printf("%d ticks\n", ticks);
    matrix_free(D, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks @chqrlie the code includes many things to learn.