# Recursive Divide & Conquer Technique

Tags: c

```
int **matMult(int **mat1,int **mat2,int **res,int N){

    static int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    if(i>=N)
    return 0;

    else if(i<N) 
    {
      if(j<N) 
      {
         if(k<N)
         {
             res[i][j]+=mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
             k++;
             matMult(mat1,mat2,res,N);
         }

             k=0;
             j++;
             matMult(mat1,mat2,res,N);
      }
        j=0;
        i++;
        matMult(mat1,mat2,res,N);
    }
return res;
}
```

output : 
Enter the value of N : 64
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

after 64 size it shows this error

Comment: Did you try for N = 2? Might be easier to track down the problem.

Comment: If you are going to multiply matrices of size `8192 x 8192`, don't use recursion. It will most likely result in stack overflow. Switch to using the simpler, easier to understand, looping method.

Comment: @RSahu *It will most likely result in stack overflow.* - Yes it will. Either a stack overflow, or a question on this page, or both. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no obvious problem in the code itself. If it works for smaller N's stack overflow can be suspected for N=64.

Using recursion for matrix multiplication is well know approach:

[Matrix Multiplication](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~leparker/Courses/CS581-spring14/Lectures/3-Jan-16-Master-Mthd-Matrix-Mult-no-answers.pdf)

[Matrix multiplication using the Divide and Conquer paradigm](https://shivathudi.github.io/jekyll/update/2017/06/15/matr-mult.html)

For practical C solution check:

[Matrix Multiplication using divide and conquer approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994405/matrix-multiplication-using-divide-and-conquer-approach)

[Strassen-recursive-matrix-multiplication.c](https://github.com/sangeeths/stanford-algos-1/blob/master/strassen-recursive-matrix-multiplication.c)

BTW: Your code is very similar to posted here: [C Program to Perform Matrix Multiplication using Recursion](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-matrix-multiplication-using-recursion/).